# What Is AUTHID in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i know its used for Definer and invoker rights in Oracle, I just want to know what is the full form of AUTHID? tried google, but couldn't find anything.Is it Author or Authority ? or what ?tell me someone...

Comment: The AUTHID clause instructs Oracle as to whether the routine is to be run with the invoker's rights (CURRENT_USER), or with the Owner rights (DEFINER). If the clause is not specified, Oracle will default to using the AUTHID DEFINER.

Comment: This is all explained in the ["Using Invoker's Rights or Definer's Rights (AUTHID Clause)" documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809).

Answer (score 2):

AUTHID is the keyword. That is the "full form".

I guess it's short for AUTHORIZATION ID, in that it defines what user id to use when verifying the authorised privileges need to run the PL/SQL.